# Spring Data Elasticsearch : @Field and non @Field all got indexed

Tags: spring, elasticsearch, spring-data

I chose to use my @Entity class to be marked with @Document as well, so that saving the overhead of maintaining the DTOs.

Now, when trying to index into elasticsearch these entities, they got stored into elastic with all properties (Unless i explicitly mark those unwanted with @JsonIgnore).

Could anyone just explain to me what really happens, and if it is possible to just selectively chose specific properties.

**Note : marking some of them a @Field does not make any difference**

Answer (score 3):

I found a workaround that might be helpful for some.

**1. Create a Custom EntityMapper**
EntityMapper is an interface that comes with the spring data elasticsearch package `org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core`, this interface has one implementation class by default called `DefaultEntityMapper` with two methods to override.

> public String mapToString(Object object) throws IOException;

```
SimpleFilterProvider filters = new SimpleFilterProvider();
filters.setDefaultFilter(SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.filterOutAllExcept(fieldsNotToFilter));
filters.setFailOnUnknownId(false);
String dtoAsString = objectMapper.writer(filters).writeValueAsString(object);
```

Note that you need **@JsonFilter("filterName")** annotation to mark the entity class.

**2. Inject the created CustomEntityMapper into elasticsearch:transport-client**
bean name="entityMapper" class="com.modym.core.search.CustomEntityMapper

Answer (score 3):

You are right, also fields without `@Field` are included. But:

1. They are NOT indexed and not present in the mapping
2. Spring data (a not so mature and so valuable project) Jsonizes all fields by default, so the problem is Spring Data as you are saying, but instead of your complex solution you can do add this annotation to your entity:

   `@Document( indexName = INDEX_NAME, type = TYPE, shards = 1, replicas = 0 )
   @JsonIgnoreProperties( value = {"field1", "field2", ..., "fieldN"} )
   public class Entity {`

Comment: Are you sure that fields without `@Field` annotation are not indexed? I my project I didn't include any `@Field` annotation and my objects are searchable(which means all field are indexed)

Answer (score 2):

See Field description in: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/reference/html/#elasticsearch.mapping.meta-model.annotations  It states:

> @Field: Applied at the field level and defines **properties of the field**, most of the attributes map to the respective Elasticsearch Mapping definitions

I.e. *@Field* annotation defines field properties, not its presence in a mapping.

If you don't want to map a variable you have (at least) two options:

1. Use *@JsonIgnore* annotation
2. Use *@Mapping* for importing your mapping file. In the mapping file, disable Dynamic Mapping - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/dynamic-mapping.html